# How to format /Date(1524210579389) in Angular

Tags: angular

How would I format Date in HTML Template? It currently displays this

/Date(1524210579389)

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: use DatePipe https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: Are you using Angular 2 or angularjs? post your code for the component.

Comment: @ShaneKm check my answer for a custom pipe, you need to pass the date value from json response to the pipe in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to create a custom pipe to format the date in `/Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/` format to a json date object with timezone. Then you can use the built in `DatePipe` of angular on top of that to get the required format without splitting the date.

Usually this type of format is returned by .NET MVC json serializer while serializing DateTime value in JSON. This problem does not exists in WEB API 2 as web api uses JSON.NET for serializing the DateTime when we return a http response.

**Custom date pipe code**

custom-date.pipes.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
/*
 * Formats a /Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/ into a JSON Date object
 * Takes an argument as input of actual date value in /Date(xxxxxxxxxxxxx)/ format.
 * Usage:
 *   date-value | customDateFormat
 * Example:
 *   {{ '/Date(1402034400000)/' | customDateFormat}}
*/
@Pipe({name: 'customDateFormat'}  )
export class CustomDateFormat implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any): Date {
       var customDate = new Date(value.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);  
       return  customDate;
  }
}
```

**Component code**
 app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular 5';
  originalDate:string = '/Date(1524210579389)/';
}
```

**Usage in HTML template**

app.component.html

```
<p>Original date: {{originalDate}}</p> <br>
<p>Custom date: {{originalDate | customDateFormat|date :'short'}}
```

Here I have use built in `date :'short'` pipe to again format the result.

Here is the final output

```
Custom date: 4/20/18, 1:19 PM
```

Working demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-pipes-wiwnew

Answer (score 2):

## Without any custom pipe

Simply call `date` pipe from angular like this

```
{{getDate("/Date(1524210579389)") | date}}

getDate(value) {
    return value.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1
  }
```

<kbd>[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgccbj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)</kbd>

If need to change the format here are the options you can choose either

- https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: I have this /Date(1524210579389), i don't have just the number.

Comment: then just split this and get timestamp number from this, btw this is not a valid format of any kind of Date

Comment: @PardeepJain this is a valid format from .NET MVC json serializer.

Comment: @ShaneKm check my answer.

Comment: @ShaneKm check my answer now, what I am trying to say in order to split your Date, even without any extra pipe

Answer (score 0):

There is by default pipes provided by the angular

for example :

```
<div>
  <h2> {{binded_date | date: 'MMMM yyyy' }}</h2>
</div>
```

output :
   APRIL 2018

you can find many more examples like this on angular [datepipes](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)